# OpenSSH Windows 10 Firewall correct rules?

Tags: networking, windows-10, ssh, firewall, openssh

I'm attempting to set up a Windows-10 OpenSSH tunnel back to my office computer using Microsoft's beta [found here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/2017/12/15/using-the-openssh-beta-in-windows-10-fall-creators-update-and-windows-server-1709/), and I've run into some trouble regarding Window's Defender Firewall.

Using Wireshark, I've determined that port forwarding on my router is set up correctly, as is my client: packets are coming from the correct source, going to the correct destination, and using the correct ports. I've confirmed this by connecting to the server just fine with the firewall disabled.

The client's request arrives to the server's address, but no response is sent by the server itself (so long as the firewall is enabled): it would appear the server is not receiving the request packets. The client sends request follow ups, but eventually times out.

I have attempted (rebooting all devices along the way):

- Microsoft's recommendations as far as adding the exception in an elevated PowerShell instance (on the correct profile)
- removing and readding the exception
- [attempting to add the most liberal exceptions for the sshd program in Windows Defender's .msc GUI (image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2rKjk.jpg)
- wiping and re-installing OpenSSH afresh

I throw myself to the mercy of the StackExchange community.

What should the correct settings be? What else can I try (beyond simply lowering the firewall)? What else can I provide in this question to make my problem more answer-able?

Comment: You need to start by eliminating the networking complexities. Set up and get it working across a local network first. That should help narrow the list of possible problems.